# Userform ListBox - How to Add Multiple Selections to One Cell in a Worksheet

Tags: listbox, userform, multi-select

The code below works great when saving userform entries to the worksheet.

I've added two multiselect listboxes to the userform that are side by side and named: lstShipLeft and lstShipRight. lstShipLeft is populated with four shipping stages. Once each stage is completed, the user selects the stage, clicks a button and the stage moves to the lstShipRight listbox. When the user saves the order, I want the selection(s) in lstShipRight to be saved to the worksheet in one cell.

The line below (Column 77) works except it only shows the first item selected in the workbook, it will not show all of the items selected.

Is there a way to show all items selected and have each separated by a comma?

```
Private Sub cmbSave_Click()
Dim Shop_Order_Number As String
Shop_Order_Number = Trim(txtShopOrdNum)
Dim orderTable As ListObject 
Set orderTable = Worksheets("Master").ListObjects("tblMaster")
Dim matchRow
matchRow = Application.Match(Shop_Order_Number, orderTable.ListColumns("SHOP ORDER NUMBER").DataBodyRange, 0)
If Not IsError(matchRow) Then
    With orderTable.ListRows(matchRow)
        .Range(1, 1).Value = txtPrefix
        .Range(1, 2).Value = cboStatus
        .Range(1, 3).Value = txtSuffix
        'redacted code
        enter code here
        .Range(1, 76).Value = cboRecRev
        .Range(1, 77).Value = lstShipRight.List(lstShipRight.ListIndex)
        .Range(1, 78).Value = GetDate(Me.txtShipped.Value)
        .Range(1, 79).Value = cboName
        'redacted code
End With
End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: I changed direction and opted to a single fmMultSelectMulti listbox with ListStyle: 1 - fmListStyleOption so you need to click on a checkbox to select each item. the following is the revised code. I can get a single item to the worksheet, but still can't get multiple selected items, separated by commas to appear on the worksheet. Plus, when I click save, the checkboxes clear instead of retaining what was selected.

```
'Save Button'
Private Sub cmbSave_Click()
'redacted code here

Dim Shop_Order_Number As String
Shop_Order_Number = Trim(txtShopOrdNum)
Dim orderTable As ListObject 'Best option for reading/writing to a worksheet with a table
Set orderTable = Worksheets("Master").ListObjects("MASTER")
Dim matchRow

Dim index As Integer 'test
Dim items As String 'test
For index = 0 To lstProcess.ListCount - 1 'equals the number of items in list
    If lstProcess.Selected(index) = True Then 'index = 29 which is the number of items in the list
        If items <> vbNullString Then items = items & ", " 'separates each list item by a comma
        items = items & lstProcess.List(index) '
    End If
Next
Debug.Print index, items

matchRow = Application.Match(Shop_Order_Number, orderTable.ListColumns("SHOP ORDER NUMBER").DataBodyRange, 0)
If Not IsError(matchRow) Then
    With orderTable.ListRows(matchRow)
        .Range(1, 1).Value = txtPrefix
        .Range(1, 2).Value = cboOrderType
        .Range(1, 3).Value = cboStatus
    'redacted code here
        .Range(1, 10).Value = GetDate(Me.txtStartDate.Value)
        .Range(1, 11).Value = GetDate(Me.txtStageDue.Value)
        .Range(1, 12).Value = GetDate(Me.txtEndDate.Value)
        .Range(1, 13).Value = txtDays
        '.Range(1, 14).Value = lstProcess.List(lstProcess.ListIndex) 'Only saves one selection
        .Range(1, 14).Value = items 'tested this, but returns no items to worksheet
        .Range(1, 15).Value = txtProposal
        .Range(1, 16).Value = cboSalesPer
        .Range(1, 17).Value = txtPrimSales
    'redacted code here
        .Range(1, 114).Value = txtSTCntry
        .Range(1, 115).Value = txtEUName
        .Range(1, 116).Value = txtEUID
        .Range(1, 117).Value = Date & " " & Time 'Timestamp
    End With
End If
'redacted code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Just checking to see if anyone knows how to add multiple combo box selections to one cell in a worksheet, separated by commas.